# Spring.net and protobuf: object instantiation

Tags: protobuf-net, spring.net

We currently use protobuf-net in our application and I would like to inject properties after deserialization.

for example, if the serialize object has a property called `DataFactory`

```
namespace Project
{
    [ProtoContract]
    public class Model
    {
        [ProtoMember]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [ProtoIgnore]
        public IDataFactory DataFactory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in the `Spring.config` file, you have the definition of your interface:

```
<object id="IDataFactory" type="Project.Impl.DataFactory, Project" />
```

How could I say (or associate) that the deserialization set the property `IDataFactory`.

**It is on open question, so please feel free to contribute with ideas or suggestions.**

I think it would be great to hook the object instantiator of protobuf-net library so that it uses Spring.NET to create object and then set properties. How do you think I could do this ?

Thanks !

**Ideal scenario**

I would like to have the DataFactory directly set by `Spring.net` after a `protobuf` deserialization.

```
Model model = Serializer.Deserialize<Model>(stream);
Assert.IsNotNull(model.DataFactory);
Assert.IsTrue(model.DataFactory is DataFactory);
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, however: protobuf-net supports both external factory methods for creating the actual "Model" instance, and serialization callbacks for invoking code at arbitrary points during serialization/deserialization. Any of those be of use?

Comment: Seriously, I'm not familiar with spring, but I am really familiar with protobuf-net; if you clarify what your ideal scenario would be I'm sure it can be done easily

Comment: Hi, thanks, I added a scenario of what I would like to do.

Comment: I'd be tempted to use the deserialization callback for that scenario, then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler approach than trying to insert Spring.NET into the instantiation of the object by ProtoBuf is to ask Spring.NET to configure the dependencies of your object *after* its been constructed.  The `IObjectFactory` interface provides a method, `IObjectFactory.ConfigureObject(object target, string name)`, that is intended to do just that.

For more info, see http://springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-extension

Answer (score 3):

This is basically a code example for sbohlen's answer from earlier.

Say you have the following Spring.Net xml config file objects.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">

  <object id="IDataFactory" type="Project.Impl.DataFactory, Project" />

  <object id="MyModel" type="MyNameSpace.Model, MyAssembly">
    <property name="DataFactory" ref="IDataFactory" />    
  </object>

</objects>
```

Then you can do:

```cs
public void Main(...)
{
    var ctx = new XmlApplicationContext("objects.xml");

    Model mdl;

    using (var file = File.OpenRead("mymodel.bin"))
    {
        mdl = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Model>(file);
    }

    ctx.ConfigureObject(mdl, "MyModel");

    // mdl.DataFactory will be injected with your idDatafactory instance
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This shows some of the points you can use to intercept various steps in deserialization:

```
using System;
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;

[ProtoContract]
class Foo
{
    [ProtoBeforeDeserialization]
    private void DoThisBeforeDeserializing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I iz bein deserialized");
    }
    [ProtoAfterDeserialization]
    private void DoThisAfterDeserializing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I haz been deserialized");
    }
    private static Foo UseThisToMakeInstances()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I is being created");
        // you could use anything you want here - maybe
        // an IOC/DI-based construction
        return new Foo();
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof (Foo), true)
              .SetFactory("UseThisToMakeInstances");

        // just using this as a template, so I can use the serializer
        var obj = new Foo(); 

        // this does a serialize/deserialize pair
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(obj);
    }
}
```

(there is support for similar using different signatures, and passing in context, etc). With the combination of those three interception points (object creation, before deserialization, after deserialization) it seems to me that most things should be possible.

Comment: Hi, this is a neat solution, but I don't have the hand on the model object code, so I chose the other solution.